# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS suspends despite my actions

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, suspend, hibernate

Every evening I lock my machine and when I come back the next morning it has been suspended. The only way to wake it is to do a power button kill and reboot.
I have taken these steps to attempt to prevent suspesion.

```
$ systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
● sleep.target
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit sleep.target is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● suspend.target
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit suspend.target is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● hibernate.target
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit hibernate.target is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● hybrid-sleep.target
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit hybrid-sleep.target is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

I also uncommented some entries.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.

[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=ignore 
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```

Any suggestions to what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you told the desktop not to suspend? (https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.12/power_management.html?highlight=suspend)  as if you lock your screen, the desktop is still behind it & active as its logged in

Comment: The suspends was set to off before I edited /etc/systemd/logind.conf
Now that option does not exist.